# How to save calculated values in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a textbox in a form that I created.

I want to add an expression in the textbox's Control Source property.
I also want to bind the textbox to a field in the table using Control Source propety of the textbox.

Is there any way I can add a field name and an expression in the control source property of a particular textbox?

The expression basically adds up couple of numbers and displays the output in that textbox. And I want the output to be stored in a field in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could link the text box to the table control source and then set the value of the text box to the result of the expression in the AfterUpdate property on the two objects the contain the values you want to add.

For example

```
me.textbox.value= int1 + int2
```

This value should then be written to the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text box named `txtMy_field` which is bound to a field named `My_field` in your form's record source, you could use the form's on current event to load the sum of those other two numbers into `txtMy_field`.

If you don't want to over-ride existing values stored in `My_field` ...

```
If IsNull(Me.txtMy_field) = True Then
    Me.txtMy_field = Number1 + Number2
End If
```

If you do want to over-ride existing values stored in `My_field`, eliminate the `IsNull()` condition.

```
Me.txtMy_field = Number1 + Number2
```

If `Number1` and `Number2` are from other controls on your form, you could also use their after update events to update `txtMy_field` value on demand.

However, I'm unsure how well I understand your question.  These are only general suggestions and I hope they point you to something useful.  Incidentally, if those two numbers come from two different forms (as in one of your previous questions) and you intend to display and store their sum via a third form, this could be more challenging than it appears from this question.

Comment: Especially if the two other forms include tables and the data may or may not have updated. The mind boggles.

Answer (score -1):

If you have textboxes with names `text1` and `text2` and you will save your answer in `text3`
you should give this code in `text3` properties Control Source:

```
=Val([text1])+Val([text2])
```