# How to get combo box selection to fill related fields with data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table `[inventory]` with inventory items, and a bunch of columns with different information for those. Mainly, `part#`, `description`, `price`. I am trying to create both a purchase order form `[POForm]` and, and a inventory transactions form `[TransactionsForm]`, but that one thing I've been stuck on is getting a combo box look up I use to select the `part#` from `[inventory]`, to also fill my fields for `description`, and `price` for that item in my form. I need the fields that are filled to be able to have formula's run off of them, and the information to be saved into the table for that form `[TransactionsTable]`, `[POTable]`.

I've tried making my `part#` combo box include the fields for the `description` and `price`, and using `=[part#].[column](x)` in the other fields as a lookup, and it looks right visually, but that is apparently just a visual of that data, but technically the field is still blank, because those other fields remain empty in the table for that form, and I am not able to run a formula off the price.

Comment: Saving calculated value requires code (macro or VBA).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save calculated values in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936536/how-to-save-calculated-values-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding and please correct me if I am wrong. you have a form that shows your inventory data Part# Description & price. This form has a combo box that allows you to select a particular part # to view its related record data description and price.

Now you want to click a command button after selecting a particular part # to update your transaction form and POtable.

1.you have to create a query,

2.insert the inventory table in it

3.select append from the query type in the ms access ribbon

4.a window will appear, choose the transaction table as the destination table to append to.

5.double click on the fields that you want to retrieve its data from the inventory table

6.then in the table below in the query itself in the "append to" row you will find drop-down menu including all the fields from the transaction table. choose the corresponding fields. note if the fields have the same name in both tables access will do it automatically.

7.in the criteria row type the following [Forms]![Inventory Form Name]![the name of the field in the form].  do that for each field in the happen query.

8.save the query and name it

9.go-to design view in your inventory form and create a command button, in the click on event creat macro  of the following: openquery-->type the append query name

10.save and close macro builder

11.open your form, select part#, click on the button

12.access will ask you to confirm appending process. click ok/yes

13.check your transaction table to confirm that the append process was successfully performed

14.Tip if you do not want the confirmation msg of append to appear, in the click on event go to the macro builder and choose in the ribbon show all actions then in the first line of the macro builder insert setwarnings - NO

the same is to be applied for the POtable.

Anyways, I hope you find this clear and helpful but I have only one concern you do not have to append part description and price in transaction and PO tables as you already have this data in your database in the inventory table. Generally speaking no need to include the same information in multiple tables otherwise you are not benefitting from the idea of a relational database.

I hope I addressed your inquiry.